# Loading Audio Objects with Javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm trying to make a game which requires audio files, which are to be downloaded from dropbox, and I want to make a loading screen that will stop the game until all the Audio has been loaded? But this isn't working, I'm getting to loadMusic and the callback never gets called

IN SHORT, what event listener fires when an Audio object is loaded? (Ready to play) And if there isn't how can I check for one?

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Game</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/Canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/Menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/Menus.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/Music.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/SFX.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/Loading.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/Wait.js"></script>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load',onLoad,false);
function onLoad(){

    //GAME_MENU.hide();
    SFX.CLICK.addEventListener('canplaythrough',function test(){
```

alert('test');}
);

```
}
function doneLoading(){
    //done loading resources
    startMenu();
    GAME_MENU.show();
    GameBg = new Background('backgroundCanvas');
    GameBg.setImage(Backgrounds.MAIN_MENU);
    MUSIC_PLAYER.playTrack(TRACKS.MAIN_MENU);
}

</script>
</head>

<body style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:0px">
<div id="hideImages"></div>
<div id="gameScreen">

    <canvas id="backgroundCanvas" class="canvas"></canvas>
    <canvas id="playerCanvas" class="canvas"></canvas>
    <canvas id="attackCanvas" class="canvas"></canvas>
    <canvas id="outerCanvas" class="canvas"></canvas>

    <div id="menu" style="visibility:hidden;" class="canvas">
        <div id="menuTitle" class="menuButton" style="margin-top:200px;font-size:50px;color:black; background-color:gray;height:50px;width:600px;cursor:default;">

        </div>
        <ul id="items" style="margin:0px auto;margin-left:-40px;margin-top:10px;">
        </ul>
    </div>

    <footer id="footer"></footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Loading.js

```
MUSIC_ID = 0;
SFX_ID = 1;
loaded = 0;
function loadResources(){
    loadMusic();
}
function loadResources2(){
    loadSFX();
}
function loadMusic(){
    console.log('Loading Music');
    for(var x=0;x<TRACKS.list.length;x++){
        var track = TRACKS.list[x];
        track.preload = true;
        track.addEventListener('loadeddata',function(){loaded++;},false);
    }
    sleepCheck(MUSIC_ID, loadResources2);
}
function loadedMusic(){
    if(loaded==TRACKS.list.length)
        sleepCheck(MUSIC_ID);
        loaded = 0;
}
function loadSFX(){
    console.log('Loading SFX');
    for(var x=0;x<SFX.list.length;x++){
        var track = SFX.list[x];
        track.preload = true;
        track.addEventListener('loadeddata',function(){loaded++;},false);
    }
    sleepCheck(SFX_ID, doneLoading);
}
function loadedSFX(){
    if(loaded==SFX.list.length)
        sleepCheck(SFX_ID);
        loaded = 0;
}
```

Wait.js

```
Sleeps = new Object();
Sleeps.sleepChecks = [];
Sleeps.addSleepCheck =
    function(id,callback){
        this.sleepChecks[id] = callback;
    };
function sleep(millis, callback) {
    setTimeout(function()
            { callback(); }
    , millis);
}
function sleepCheck(id,callback){
    if(Sleeps.sleepChecks[id]!=null){
        Sleeps.sleepChecks[id];
    }else{
        Sleeps.addSleepCheck(id,callback);
    }
}
```

Music.js

```
var path = 'Resources/Audio/Music/';
MUSIC_PLAYER = new Object();
MUSIC_PLAYER.volume = 0.5;
MUSIC_PLAYER.currentTrack = null;
MUSIC_PLAYER.playTrack =
function playTrack(track){
    if(typeof track === 'number' && track%1 == 0)
        track = this.list[track];
    if(this.currentTrack==track)
        return;
    this.stop();
    this.currentTrack = track;
    this.currentTrack.loop = true;
    this.restart();
    this.start();
    return true;
};
MUSIC_PLAYER.start =
    function startMusic(){
        if(this.currentTrack==null)
            return false;
        if(this.currentTrack.ended||this.currentTrack.paused){
            this.currentTrack.play();
            this.currentTrack.volume = this.volume;
            return true;
        }
    };
MUSIC_PLAYER.stop =
    function stopMusic(){
        if(this.currentTrack == null)
            return false;
        if(!(this.currentTrack.ended||this.currentTrack.paused))
            this.currentTrack.pause();
        return true;
    };
MUSIC_PLAYER.setVolume =
    function setVolume(vol){
        this.volume = vol/10;
        if(this.currentTrack==null)
            return false;
        this.currentTrack.volume = this.volume;
    };
MUSIC_PLAYER.restart =
    function restartMusic(){
        this.currentTrack.currentTime = 0;
    };
TRACKS = new Object();
TRACKS.list = [];
TRACKS.MAIN_MENU = TRACKS.list[0] = new Audio('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/klauhgst6ucwrdh/Title.mp3?dl=1&token_hash=AAHb6Cc9de8-PUKOATpgciLJmoQIM1-o6thalq3GMSdf-w');
TRACKS.CREDITS_MENU = TRACKS.list[1] = new Audio('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/6juu8a0797gamlg/Credits.mp3?dl=1&token_hash=AAH666_2nLK-WYNbh4z7Gj4HrjqfIIZoZwNodW6nTZyVfA');
```

SFX.js

```
var path = 'Resources/Audio/SFX/';
SFX = new Object();
SFX.volume = 0.5;
SFX.list = [];
SFX.CLICK = SFX.list[0] = new Audio('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mb4uzm20car4ynx/Click.mp3?dl=1&token_hash=AAGIkSpcaG-WR2nz9uBi94TzmuWzOIhLsDipLtjFY9PzSA');
function playSound(sound){
    if(typeof sound === 'number' && sound%1 == 0)
        sound = SFX.list[sound];
    try{
        sound.volume = SFX.volume/10;
        sound.play();
        return true;
    }catch(e){}
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It depends on your definition of "loaded". `canplaythrough` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/canplaythrough can help in this case, but it does not guarantee that the browser has downloaded the entire content (nothing does, I think).

Comment: I tried using 'canplaythrough' but that didn't work :/

Comment: What is your definition of "loaded"?

Comment: yeah i just realized that I changed the loaded++ to loadedMusic() and loadedSFX() respectively and added loaded++ in them

loaded is at the top set to 0

Comment: No, I mean, what does "Audio object is loaded" mean? Do you want to know when the entire file has loaded? Do you want to know when enough of the file has loaded and the browser can start playing it?
As I wrote, I do not think the browser loads the entire file anyway, not even with `preload = true`. I think you have to XMLHttpRequest the audio file and once that is loaded (`onload` or `onreadystatechange` and `readyState === 4`), convert it into an audio object.

Comment: I would want to check that the browser can play the WHOLE file but checking is the browser can start the audio is fine too

Comment: Your code is too complex and incomplete to be readable as it is. Can you simplify it (show HTML and JavaScript, load a single <audio> and see if the event fires, for example)?

Comment: I've tried
SFX.CLICk.addEventListener('canplay',function test(){alert('test');});

Comment: That tells me nothing. Please, simplify your code and edit the question accordingly.

Comment: I requested that you simplify the code, not add dozen more lines...